# C - error: initializer element is not constant when creating struct *

Tags: c, unix, gcc, struct

I have been writing a terminal application in C and i've been having a weird issue with structs. When I try and compile I get the error "error: initializer element is not constant". Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is my code:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    char style;
} Pixel;

Pixel *pixels = (Pixel *)malloc(9*128);
```

Comment: How you know `sizeof(Pixel)` is `9`?

Comment: This code is not in any function. However, a _call_ (to malloc in this case) can only be in a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling malloc outside function.

This will solve your problem:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    char style;
} Pixel;

int main(void) {
    Pixel *pixels = malloc(9 * 128);
}
```

In C you cannot call function on variable init, if variable is not inside any function.

```
int a = 5; //OK
int b = myfunc(); //ERROR, this was your case
int main() {
    int c = 5; //OK
    int d = myfunc(); //OK
}
```

---

As from code inspect, I assume you think that your `sizeof(Pixel)`is `9` bytes but this may not be the case. When you call your malloc, use this code:

```
Pixel *pixels = malloc(sizeof(Pixel) * 128);
```

This code will allocate memory for `128 Pixel` structures in a single row on any platform.

---

Further reading:

[Structure padding and packing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing)

[Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Thank you so much! Since I am relatively new to C, I get confused with having global variables sometimes!

Comment: If it works for you, mark it as correct answer. @emd22

Answer (score 1):

This code aparently is not in any function. Then the expression following `=` can only be an initializer, and an initializer must be static (i.e. can be calculated at compile time) However, a call (to malloc in this case) can only be in a function. So the compiler complains.

The following would be correct:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    char style;
} Pixel;

int main(void)
{
    Pixel *pixels = (Pixel *)malloc(sizeof(Pixel)*128);
    //...
}
```

Comment: It would be correct if you didn't chop off the last bracket :)

Comment: @See Dart, you have me puzzled :-))?

Comment: Your edit fixed the syntax error I was highlighting.